# How to connect to second DB for all read queries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I've got to write an app where all read queries should be sent to a specific DB, and all write queries should be sent to a different DB.  Both databases are Postgres.

I found [Secondbase](https://github.com/customink/secondbase), and that looks promising, but it doesn't define a specific way to accomplish what I'm after.

I'm thinking the most straightforward approach would be to use secondbase, and just put before hooks on all of the active record functions to switch connections based on the need.  It seems like a hack though, so I'm not sure.

Another approach would be to subclass all of my models in to `read_` and `write_` versions I suppose, since you can define a secondbase DB connection at the class level.  This approach seems overly complicated.

Are one of these better than the other?  Have you accomplished this behavior in another way?

Comment: It would be useful to specify which database (e.g., mysql, postgres, etc.) you're using, as some database driver libraries can route read and write queries to different databases (e.g., the MySQL connector for Java can do this).

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished this through the following:

Create `#{Rails.env}_read` and `#{Rails.env}_write` `database.yml` for each Rails.env. Configured the write database as `#{Rails.env}` so that migrations can run.

Add a before hook on each controller function that points to the appropriate connection:

```
def connect_to_read_db
  DatabaseConnector.connect_to_db('read')
end

def connect_to_write_db
  DatabaseConnector.connect_to_db('write')
end
```

Create a class and method responsible for the swapping.

```
class DatabaseConnector

    class << self
        def connect_to_db(function)
            if !(Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.test?)
            if ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config[:function] != function
                Rails.logger.debug "Gathering DB details"
                seed_file = Rails.root.join('config', 'database.yml')
                loaded_yml_file = YAML::load_file(seed_file)
                connection_name = "#{Rails.env}_#{function}"
                Rails.logger.debug "attempting connection to: #{connection_name}" 
                db_details = loaded_yml_file[connection_name]
                Rails.logger.debug "database details:" 
                db_details.each do |d|
                    Rails.logger.debug(d)
                end
                ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
                  adapter: db_details['adapter'],
                  port: db_details['port'],
                  pool: db_details['pool'],
                  timeout: db_details['timeout'],
                  encoding: db_details['encoding'],
                  host: db_details['host'],
                  database: db_details['database'],
                  username: db_details['username'],
                  password: db_details['password']
                )
            end
            end
        end
    end
end
```